# how to support un usual characters in awk command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, perl, awk

The following bash script - **read Password_from_csv.bash** perform the following

1. read the CSV password names and CSV password values
2. print  CSV password names and CSV password values  for each CSV line ( password values are from the second line )

please take a look on the second line in CSV , password are simple only **a-z** and **numbers** characters

so if I run the script , all password names and values will printed  as **example 1**

but when we set **CSV_LINE=3** in the script in order to read the third CSV line ,
the script gives us the following errors as command not found because the un usual characters as "$" or "*" or "/" or "\"  , as **example 2**

so

please advice how to change/fix the awk syntax in my bash script in order to support un usual characters 
and print the password from the third line in my CSV ?

```
 more readPassword_from_csv.bash

 #!/bin/bash



 CSV_LINE=2

  eval $(awk -v line=$CSV_LINE -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i }
            NR==line { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print sn[i] "=" $i ; exit }'    all_passwords.CSV )




   echo CSV_LINE=$CSV_LINE
   echo Password1=$Password1
   echo Password1=$Password2
   echo Password1=$Password3
   echo Password1=$Password4
   echo Password1=$Password5
   echo Password1=$Password6
   echo Password1=$Password7
   echo Password1=$Password8
```

.

```
   more  all_passwords.CSV
   Password1,Password2,Password3,Password4,Password5,Password6,Password7,Password8
   hdehbcr,fre435fr,443f4,544fr4fr4,454534rf4,r3443tr,5345rd,545trr34
   &^#GTR$@H,@Y^%ER$%*&*UJ,**U&^#%%@$^&//\\,^T%!#&^YG.+___KI*&HHTY,%%@$#!%^#&,P/\06E87*UHG11#,edehu234#@!&,~hum&T%6e4
```

.

another example of CSV , in this case we have spaces:

```
      Password1,Password2,Password3,Password4,Password5,Password6,Password7,Password8
      &^#G TR  /  /  $@H,@Y^%"  E  "R$%*&*UJ,**U&^#%%@$^&//\\,^T%!#&^YG.+___KI*&HHTY,%%@$#!%^#&,P/\06E87*UHG11#,edehu234#@!&,~hum&T%6e4
```

**example1**

example of script output when I read the second line ( **CSV_LINE=2** ) in CSV

```
  ./readPassword_from_csv.bash 
   CSV_LINE=2
   Password1=hdehbcr
   Password1=fre435fr
   Password1=443f4
   Password1=544fr4fr4
   Password1=454534rf4
   Password1=r3443tr
   Password1=5345rd
   Password1=545trr34
```

**example 2**

example of script output when I read the thired  line ( **CSV_LINE=3** ) in CSV

```
  ./readPassword_from_csv.bash 



 ./readPassword_from_csv.bash 
 ./readPassword_from_csv.bash: line 8: ^#%%@$^: command not found
 ./readPassword_from_csv.bash: line 8: //\: No such file or directory
 ./readPassword_from_csv.bash: line 8: ^YG.+___KI*: command not found
 ./readPassword_from_csv.bash: line 8: HHTY: command not found
 ./readPassword_from_csv.bash: line 8: T%6e4: command not found
 CSV_LINE=3
 Password1=
 Password1=
 Password1=
 Password1=
 Password1=
 Password1=
 Password1=
 Password1=
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use quotes in your `eval` + `awk` command:

```
eval $(awk -v line=$CSV_LINE -F, 'NR==1 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) sn[i]=$i }
     NR==line { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print sn[i] "=\"" $i "\""; exit }' all_passwords.CSV )
```

But there can be better alternatives of using `eval` (e.g. indirect reference) here.

#### UPDATE:

**Alternative pure BASH solution without using `eval`**:

```
CSV_LINE=2
vars=()
c=1
while IFS=, read -ra arr; do
   if ((c==1)); then
      vars+=("${arr[@]}")
   elif ((c==CSV_LINE)); then
      for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
         declare ${vars[$i]}="${arr[$i]}"
      done
   fi
   ((c++))
done < all_passwords.csv
```

Comment: I actually thought he was referring to non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Yes I also thought same initially but after looking at sample data I realized he meant `non alpha-numerals`.

Comment: I FOUND a BUG , if password with spaces and as --> &^#G TR  /  /  $@H,@Y^%"  E  "

Comment: awk - need to support spaces !

Comment: Did you try non-eval solution?

Comment: That is **not correct**. I just tried pure BASH solution and it sets `"$Passord1"` as `&^#G TR  /  /  $@H`.

Comment: what I want is to print the values from CSV ( inspite they have spaces or non numerical char or even char --> "

Comment: try passowrd as --> $&NJ* " / JKJK#* "" JHG

Comment: I used same and got `$Password1` as `$&NJ* " / JKJK#* "" JHG`. What else did you expect?

Comment: in your bash script what parameter is the - $CSV_LINE ?

Comment: Just set `CSV_LINE=2` before that script or see updated answer.

Comment: I write your code in function but the problem is that other function cant read the parameter values - WHY?

Comment: Better not to use a function for it since script is creating dynamic variables.